# Reading Text From Word Document

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to read a word document and loop through the amount of paragraphs there and get the text in that paragraph.

For some reason the count is returning '7' when it should be returning '3'.

Here is the code i have written:

```
Dim missing As Object = System.Type.Missing

Dim application As New DOCApplication.Application()
Dim document As DOCApplication.Document = application.Documents.Open(OpenFileDialog.FileName, missing, missing, missing,
                                                                        missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing,
                                                                        missing, missing, missing, missing, missing)

Dim data As New List(Of String)()

For index = 0 To document.Paragraphs.Count

    Dim temp As String = document.Paragraphs(index + 1).Range.Text.Trim()
    If temp <> String.Empty Then
        data.Add(temp)
    End If

Next
```

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: 1. use `For index=1 to ..` (as it is, `index+1` is (probably) out of bounds). 2. What count is returning '7'? 3. Easiest way to debug is to have your code list the contents of those paragraphs.

Comment: @Jongware `document.Paragraphs.Count` is returning '7'. After the index change the code works but the amount of paragraphs count is still incorrect?

Comment: Are there 4 empty paragraphs?